# Accessing actionView in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I would like to create an always-expanded search window in my action bar. I am using the ActionBar Sherlock library. According to some samples I have found, this code should do the trick

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = this.getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_bar_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();  //returns null
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);


    return true;
}
```

however, getActionView(); returns null.
Is there some other way to get to the searchView, so that I can call the setIconifiedByDefault(false); method ?
I would like to keep the definition of the searchView in the xml file as follows

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_bar_search"
          android:title="@string/action_bar_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_magnify"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
    </menu>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your issue is probably with your XML. Change `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` to `android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"`

Comment: I haven't tried it out yet, but it sounds very logical. Thanks a lot for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're using correct `R.menu...` link? Also try to use `getMenuInflater();` instead of `getSupportMenuInflater();`

Comment: The menu is defined in a file action_bar.xml in res/menu, plus the findItem() method does return the correct(I think) object.

Comment: I am using getSupportMenuInflater(); to call the menuInflater of the ActionBarSherlock library, but it should behave exactly the same as the stock version.